# ProxyFactoryBean class has no definition for CommonsPool2TargetSource?

Tags: java, spring, jar

I'm facing trouble while creating pool for my POJO class.
Here is my code snippet:

```
    @Bean
    public CommonsPool2TargetSource poolTargetSource() {
        CommonsPool2TargetSource commonsPool2TargetSource = new CommonsPool2TargetSource();
        commonsPool2TargetSource.setMinIdle(5);
        commonsPool2TargetSource.setMaxSize(50);
        commonsPool2TargetSource.setTargetClass(JioTUURL.class);
        return commonsPool2TargetSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProxyFactoryBean proxyFactoryBean() {
        ProxyFactoryBean proxyFactoryBean = new ProxyFactoryBean();
        proxyFactoryBean.setTargetSource(poolTargetSource());//The type org.apache.commons.pool2.PooledObjectFactory cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
        return proxyFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodInvokingFactoryBean poolConfigAdvisor() {
        MethodInvokingFactoryBean poolConfigAdvisor = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
        poolConfigAdvisor.setTargetObject(commonsPoolTargetSource());
        poolConfigAdvisor.setTargetMethod("getMaxIdle");
        return poolConfigAdvisor;
    }
```

I am getting an error message at compilation time as mentioned in comment.

Earlier I was using CommonsPoolTargetSource but came to conclusion that it is deprecated.

jars/version I am using:
*Spring 4.3.1,
aopalliance-1.0.jar,
commons-logging-1.2.jar,
commons-pool-1.6.jar,
core-io-1.3.1.jar,
rxjava-1.1.6.jar,
slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar,
slf4j-simple-1.7.21.jar*

Comment: Reference : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop-api.html#aop-ts-pool

Comment: Replaced the commons-pool-1.6.jar with commons-pool2-2.4.2.jar and the error disappeared.